# How to use variables in RabbitMQ Config file for LDAP

Tags: tfs, rabbitmq, azure-devops

I have the following config file setup to use LDAP for RabbitMQ authentication, how do I populate the server, port, for instance, using environment variables or pass them in during a TFS build?

```
[
 {rabbit,[{auth_backends, [{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal},
                           rabbit_auth_backend_internal]}]},
  {rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]},
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"}
  ]},
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
   [ {servers,               ["0.0.0.0"]},
     {dn_lookup_attribute,   "sAMAccountName"},
     {dn_lookup_base,        "DC=AD,DC=company,DC=com"},
     {user_dn_pattern,       "${username}@company.com"},
     {use_ssl,               true},
     {port,                  636},
     {log,                   network}
     ]
   }
].
```

Comment: In Windows, we should use the environment variables of the System Properties for modifying the environment variables of RabbitMQ, maybe you can try creating the variables in OS, See https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781783981526/2/ch02lvl1sec15/the-rabbitmq-environment-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass them during a TFS Build, you can add a Powershell script task in your build definition to populate the values via Regex or use some build tasks like: [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to update the config file.